# como implementar dos filtros de busqueda que compartan la informacion en angular

Tags: angular, formularios, busqueda

Tengo la necesidad de hacer un filtro de busqueda, algo asi como el de esta pagina: [paginaModelo](https://www.compreoalquile.com) , si ven el en el inicio tiene un filtro sencillo, una vez que se hace click en el botón "Buscar" se carga una página con los datos que concuerdan con ese filtro , la paginacion y un filtro mas específico en la parte izquierda de la página. Yo estoy intentando hacer algo igual, el problema es que tengo una componente con un formulario reactivo con el filtro principal y luego que se hace click en el boton "Buscar" se carga otra componente (a la cual deberia pasar los datos del formulario principal) para poder hacer las demas peticiones en la paginacion. Mi duda es en como pasar esos datos del formulario a la otra componente para continuar con la busqueda desde la otra componente? cual seria la forma recomendada de hacer eso? recien estoy comenzando con angular y no he encontrado informacion referente a este caso, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecerìa. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que hablas de comunicación entre componentes. Lee esto https://medium.com/@javifont/3-formas-de-comunicarse-entre-componentes-angular-b349ada25797. Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. lo que hice para resolver fue pasar los valores de los input del formulario a traves de [routerLink] a la otra componente y luego utilizo esos parametros para el filtro. El gran problema ahora es que cuando recargo esa vista no me carga la informacion, imagino que debo tener algo en el onInit para que cuando recargue use los ultimos datos que se le pasaron para mostrar la información.

Comment: Puedes inyectar un servicio en ambos componentes que sirva como medio de comunicación. La otra es que no uses la redirección de routerlink y hagas un componente reciclable que este ocultó.

Comment: Si, estoy usando un servicio. Tengo un problema que cuando recargo la pagina no muestra la infomacion por la que filtre, es decir, se pierde. como podria hacer para que al recargar la pagina vuelva a mostrar la misma informacion. algo asi: https://www.compreoalquile.com/apartamentos-en-venta.html en esa pagina, si recargas se vuelven a mostrar los inmuebles por los que ya habia filtrado antes, en mi caso no se muestran y se pierde toda la informacion que estaba mostrando.